# Bounded functions, existence of a functional with a given norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, definite-integrals, normed-spaces

Let $\mathcal{B} ([0,1])$ be the space of all bounded real functions on $[0,1]$ with sup norm.

Prove that for each $x_0 \in [0,1]$ there exists a functional $\varphi \in \mathcal{B} ([0,1])'$, $|| \varphi || =1$ such that $\varphi (f) = \lim _{t \rightarrow x_0}f(t)$ if $f$ has a limit in $x_0$

This means that we need  $| \varphi (f)| \le \sup_{t \in [0,1]}|f(t)| $ and there has to be an $f$ for which $| \varphi (f)| = \sup_{t \in [0,1]}|f(t)|$.

The problem is that the functions are bounded, not necessarily continuous.

That's why I've been thinking about Hahn-Banach theorem. We have a subspace $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ of bounded functions. We define $\varphi$ there, it has to be continuous, and then extend it to all bounded functions on $[0,1]$

And a similar question:

Prove that  there exists a functional $\varphi \in \mathcal{B} ([0,1])'$, $|| \varphi || = \frac{3}{4}$ such that $\varphi (f) = \int_{1/4}^1 f(t)dt $ if $f$ is continuous.

I suppose one could use Hahn-Bamach theorem here, but I don't know how to do that exactly

Could you tell me how to handle this sort of problems?

Thank you!

Comment: You're on the right track. Hint for the second question, $\phi(f)=\int_0^11_{[1/4,1]}(t)f(t)dt$, where $1_A$ is the indicator function for the set $A$.

Comment: Thank you. I also wat to make sure of one thing. Is continuity of $\varphi$ due to $|\varphi (f) - \varphi (g)| = |\lim f(t) - \lim g(t)| = |\lim (f(t) - g(t))| \le \sup |f(t) - g(t)| = ||f - g||$?

Comment: In the second case we would have $|\varphi (f) - \varphi (g)| = |\int_0^1 1_{[1/4,1]} (f(t) - g(t))dt| \le \int_{1/4}^1 |f(t) - g(t)|dt \le 3/4 \sup |f(t) - g(t)| = 3/4 ||f-g||$. Is this correct? This would prove that $\varphi$ is continuous with respect to sup norm, and so we can extend it to all bounded functions on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case, fix $x_0\in[0,1]$. Let $W:=\{f\in\mathcal{B}[0,1]:\lim_{t\to x_0}f(t)\text{ exists}\}$. Then from the algebra of limits, note that $W$ is a vector space and $\phi:W\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\phi(f)=\lim_{t\to x_0}f(t)$ is a linear functional. Also note that $|\phi(f)|\leq||f||_\infty$. By using the constant function $1$, we have $||\phi||=1$. Now apply Hahn-Banach extension.